# Reading and writing values from form doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a code sample where I want to read some data from input fields and write that data to a different div.

In first section the code works properly, but in 2nd section the value is not shown. I used the alert function to check that wether value is received or not. The value is received but not shown.

What is wrong with my code? (below)

```
function preview() {
$(".preview_block").fadeIn(1000);
$("body").css("overflow","hidden");
$(".preview_block").css("overflow","auto");
/*======================Value fetch for personal details=======================*/
var fastname1 = document.forms["myform"]["fastname"].value;
if(fastname1==""){fastname1="---null---"}
var lastname1 = document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
if(lastname1==""){lastname1="---null---"}
var sex1 = document.forms["myform"]["radio"].value;
if(sex1==""){sex1="---null---"}
var clgid1 = document.forms["myform"]["clgid"].value;
if(clgid1==""){clgid1="---null---"}
var dob1 = document.forms["myform"]["dob"].value;
if(dob1==""){dob1="---null---"}
var fname1 = document.forms["myform"]["fname"].value;
if(fname1==""){fname1="---null---"}
var mname1 = document.forms["myform"]["mname"].value;
if(mname1==""){mname1="---null---"}
var gname1 = document.forms["myform"]["gname"].value;
if(gname1==""){gname1="---null---"}
var mobno1 = document.forms["myform"]["mobno"].value;
if(mobno1==""){mobno1="---null---"}
var pmobno1 = document.forms["myform"]["pmobno"].value;
if(pmobno1==""){pmobno1="---null---"}
var mail1 = document.forms["myform"]["mail"].value;
if(mail1==""){mail1="---null---"}
var addr11 = document.forms["myform"]["addr1"].value;
if(addr11==""){addr11="---null---"}
var addr21 = document.forms["myform"]["addr2"].value;
if(addr21==""){addr21="---null---"}
var city1 = document.forms["myform"]["city"].value;
if(city1==""){city1="---null---"}
var state1 = document.forms["myform"]["state"].value;
if(state1==""){state1="---null---"}
var pcode1 = document.forms["myform"]["pcode"].value;
if(pcode1==""){pcode1="---null---"}
var ps1 = document.forms["myform"]["ps"].value;
if(ps1==""){ps1="---null---"}
var po1 = document.forms["myform"]["po"].value;
if(po1==""){po1="---null---"}
var country1 = document.forms["myform"]["country"].value;
if(country1==""){country1="---null---"}
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = fastname1;
document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = lastname1;
document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = sex1;
document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = clgid1;
document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = dob1;
document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML = fname1;
document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = mname1;
document.getElementById("p8").innerHTML = gname1;
document.getElementById("p9").innerHTML = mobno1;
document.getElementById("p10").innerHTML = pmobno1;
document.getElementById("p11").innerHTML = mail1;
document.getElementById("p12").innerHTML = addr11;
document.getElementById("p13").innerHTML = addr21;
document.getElementById("p14").innerHTML = city1;
document.getElementById("p15").innerHTML = state1;
document.getElementById("p16").innerHTML = pcode1;
document.getElementById("p17").innerHTML = ps1;
document.getElementById("p18").innerHTML = po1;
document.getElementById("p19").innerHTML = country1;
/*======================Value fetch for XII standered details=======================*/
var qualification1 = $('#qualification option:selected').html();
if(qualification1==""){qualification1="---null---"}
var q1_board1 = $('#q1_board option:selected').html();
if(q1_board1==""){q1_board1="---null---"}
var clg_nm1 = document.forms["myform"]["clg_nm"].value;
if(session1==""){session1="---null---"}
var regno1 = document.forms["myform"]["regno"].value;
if(regno1==""){regno1="---null---"}
var yr_reg1 = document.forms["myform"]["yr_reg"].value;
if(yr_reg1==""){yr_reg1="---null---"}
var rollno1 = document.forms["myform"]["rollno"].value;
if(rollno1==""){rollno1="---null---"}
document.getElementById("q1").innerHTML = qualification1;
document.getElementById("q2").innerHTML = q1_board1;
document.getElementById("q3").innerHTML = clg_nm1;
document.getElementById("q4").innerHTML = regno1;
document.getElementById("q5").innerHTML = yr_reg1;
document.getElementById("q6").innerHTML = rollno1;
}
```

Comment: on your div can you try.. document.getElementById("p3").appendChild(document.createTextNode("value"));//lets see if that works... your code is a bit muddled up tho, but try that

Comment: could also please check the errors printed on the console based on your initial code

Comment: actually my code is working properly for first section but in second section this code fetch the value properly but not printed....

Comment: Assuming you are using including the jquery library as you are using $ for that second part where qualification1= $..... ?

Also without being able to see the html for the divs we are unable to tell if the problem lies in the js or that the ids are wrong on the divs

Comment: I will already try document.forms["myform"]["qualification"].value; and document.forms["myform"]["q1_board"].value; but the result was same...